# How can I convert HEX encoded Unicode to a QString?

Tags: qt, unicode, qstring, qt4.8

I have a file that contains Strings like:

```
444541191800B45D01FF00004593244700013030303535202
```

I think that these are unicode strings.
How can i convert them to a Qt QString object?
I tried the following:

```
QByteArray ar1 = inQString.toAscii();
QByteArray ar2 = QByteArray::fromHex(ar1);
QString outQString = QString::fromUtf8(ar2.data());
```

But his returns a String with only 5 Characters.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution myself. The size parameter was missing.
Correct Code:

```
QByteArray ar1 = inQString.toAscii();
QByteArray ar2 = QByteArray::fromHex(ar1);
QString outQString = QString::fromUtf8(ar2.data(), ar2.size());
```

Comment: Or just `fromUtf8(ar2)` (more concise and and ar2.data() creates an unnecessary copy; `.constData()` would avoid that)

Comment: Seems not to exist in Qt 4.8 - which i am using. Thanks anyway.